# Sorting list of files by last modified

Tags: python

I have a directory with lots of subdirectories and files in it, and I'd like to find the most recently edited files in it (they should all have been edited at the same time.)

So far, I've managed to list all the files in the directory, but trying to sort the list so I can get the most recent files throws an error, and I'm hoping someone can help me understand what is going on. :)

The code so far:

```
import os 

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in files:
        print sorted(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, name)))
```

And the error:

```
 line 5, in <module>
  print sorted(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, name)))
 TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

There are a few explanations of this error out there, but I couldn't see how they were applicable to what I'm doing here, so I could use some help.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `os.path.getmtime` is returning float. You'll probably have to create a list of file time-stamps and then sort them using `sorted()`

Answer (score 1):

```
import os 

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in sorted(files, key=lambda name:
                    os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, name))):
        print name
```

The first argument to `sorted` should always be a sequence. These are the items that will be returned by `sorted`, though perhaps in a different order. The `key` parameter can be set to a callable. The callable will be called for each item in the sequence. The value returned by the callable will be used as a proxy value, according to which the items in the sequence is sorted. For a clearer explanation, see [HOWTO Sort](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/).

Comment: You fixed the code, explained the problem, and pointed to an external resource with more information. 3 for 3! :)

Answer (score 0):

sorted may takes a sequence 
     os.path.getmtime
it wii give a floating point value

error here.you wrote like this
   sorted(10.51) #its an error

you must write like this
    sorted( [8,6,4,9,3] )

first  make a list looks like this and sort it.
     [(time,path),(time,path),(time,path)]

example code:

```
 tosort=[] #make a list
 import os 
 for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
     for name in files:
         atuple=(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, name)),path)
         tosort.append(atuple)
 tosort.sort()
```

now tosort named list will sorted